# How to preprocess raw data in the form RDF triples to perform Information Gain and Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, recommender-system

I have my dataset in the form RDF triples in various domains such as Movie, music etc.

Data is in the form of RDF triples (Subject, Property,Object (all uris). A sample input in the movie domain is displayed below.

[image: RDF sample dataset]

As far as my understanding, We need data in the form of a matrix for PCA and we need to classify data into different labels for Information gain. I need to automatically fetch relevant features(properties) from all the properties available.say 50 out  150 features.  It would be really great if someone could help me with more insight into pca and information gain and how to perform these machine learning algorithms based my raw rdf triples dataset.